# Why am I getting a 500 Internal Server Error when importing local python file?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, apache2

I've set up a local apache2 web server on my Mac. I have a button that calls a javascript function onclick. That javascript function uses JQuery .ajax to call a local python file currently named test.py (shown below). In test.py I am trying to import another local module from a python file i've named frontEndSupport.py to use a function called create_graph.

The problem is: when I click the button on my webpage that triggers all of this, I ultimately get a 500 server error.

Here is the code in test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb
#from frontEndSupport import create_graph
import datetime

print "Content-type: text\n\n";
# Create instance of FieldStorage
data= cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get data from fields
ticker = data.getvalue("ticker")
day = data.getvalue("day")

print("Ticker: {0}".format(ticker))
print("Day: {0}".format(day))
#ticker = "CSCO"
#day = datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 14, 30, 0).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#create_graph(ticker, day)
```

As it is right now, with the import from frontEndSupport commented out, it works fine. In the javascript function I create an alert with the ajax response and it gives the proper alert (Ticker: ... Day: ...) so I know that the environment is set up correctly to access and run this python script.

However when I uncomment "from frontEndSupport import create_graph" I get a 500 internal server error when clicking the button, even if I don't use create_graph so I believe simply importing this module is the problem. I have ran test.py using create_graph from the command line with hardcoded variables instead of using cgi and it works as expected.

As I said I think the problem is the import. It may have something to do with the server not knowing where the file is, but I don't know what to do to fix that (if that is the case).

Hopefully that background information was straight forward but I can clarify or provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was getting a 500 internal server error from a problem during python interpretation. Inside of frontEndSupport.py there are imports to packages installed with pip that are managed in the path to python3. My shebang needed to be #!/anaconda3/bin/python3.